# New Relic - Unbelievable Apdex score

Tags: newrelic, apdex

I've been thrown into checking the already existing New Relic installation at work which was configured by non sysadmin staff and it's probably misconfigured as all hell (I'm also a new sysadmin). New Relic is kind of intimidating, lots of information on the site, nothing I really need.

Anyways, at some point we were bombarded by a low apdex score warning so I went ahead and set the "acceptable" threshold to 10 to 40 seconds, which is quite high.

However, I'm still getting low apdex score warnings sometimes for some sites. Checking the data in new relic and there's a lot of entries that are in the "acceptable" range. I find this to be absolutely unbelievable, every time I try out our sites in GTmetrix we're in the 2.5-3 seconds range.

Our sites are incredibly low traffics, so it's most likely that most of our traffic is bots... Are bots actually causing this? Any ways to make it so that New Relic won't count bots traffic for the apdex, or just plain won't count real traffic for it and just have the new relic app check the loading speed itself?

Also, is there any good newbie guides anywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although there is nothing acceptable about 10-40 seconds, it's possible that some assets are still taking quite a while to load. Check the network tab in Chrome developer tools.

Comment: Chrome tells me around 2-4 seconds too